# $\ell^1$ is not complete for the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

> Let $\ell^\infty = \{ (u_n) | u_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|u_n| < \infty \}$ and $\ell^1 = \{ (u_n) | u_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |u_n| < \infty \}$

We know that $\ell^1 \subset \ell^\infty$, so $\ell^1$ inherits the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ of $\ell^\infty$.
We want to show that :

> 1. $\ell^1$ is not complete for the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

I considered the sequence $(u^{(n)})$ defined by $u^{(n)}_k = \frac{1}{k}$ if $k \leq n$ and $u^{(n)}_k = 0$ otherwise. This sequence doesn't converge to an element $l \in \mathcal{l}^1$. For if it does, we have necessarily that $l_k = \frac{1}{k}$ and $l \notin \ell^1$. Moreover, my guess is that this sequence is Cauchy. But how exactly do we prove that ?

My second question is:

> 2. We still endow $\ell^1$ with the norm $ \|\cdot\|_\infty$. Let $\phi : \ell^1 \times \ell^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be such
>    that $\phi(U,V) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n v_n$.  Show that $\phi$ is
>    not continuous.

I don't know which sequences $U$ and $V$ I might take with the assumption that $\phi$ is continuous in order to get a contradiction.

Can someone help ?

Comment: For the first one, you use the definition of Cauchy:  Fix $\epsilon>0$ and show there is an integer $N$ such that $||\vec{u}_k - \vec{u}_m||_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$ whenever $k,n$ are both larger than $N$.

Comment: For the second, what if you find vectors $\vec{u}_k$ such that $||\vec{u}_k||_{\infty}\rightarrow 0$ but $\phi(\vec{u}_k,\vec{u}_k)\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: For the first one, what are the cases that I should distinguish to prove that the sequence is Cauchy ? For the second, which $\vec{u}_k$ should I take ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first one, if $m>n$
$$
\|u^{(n)}-u^{(m)}\|_\infty=\sup\{(0,\ldots,0,\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+2},\ldots,\frac1m)\}=\frac1{n+1}.
$$
So the sequence is Cauchy.

For the second one, let $$u^{(n)}=v^{(n)}=\bigg(\underbrace{\frac1{\sqrt n},\ldots,\frac1{\sqrt n}}_{n \text{ times }},0,\ldots\bigg).$$
Then $\|u^{(n)}\|_\infty=\|v^{(n)}\|_\infty=\frac1{\sqrt n}\to0$, while $\phi(u^{(n)},v^{(n)})=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.